# How do I copy text from my xterm without a mouse?

Tags: linux, command-line, keyboard, xterm

I want to use part of the output of a command run from the command line in another xterm, or as part of a different command.  For instance:

```
> grep error error.log
error: can't find file ~/<some very long path>/thisfile
```

and I want to do this:

```
>ls ~/<some very long path>/
```

I know two ways to do this:
1. copy `~/<some very long path>/` with the mouse.
2. use some combination of `head`/`tail`/`awk`/`sed`/`perl`/`cut`/etc... to extract only what I need from the output and then use *that* inside backticks.

Is there any way to copy text without using the mouse?  The example that comes to mind is visual mode inside VIM, but I don't know how to do that inside the xterm.

Comment: Related/indentical questions elsewhere: http://superuser.com/q/555886/128768; http://stackoverflow.com/q/1536757/1172302; http://superuser.com/q/228236/128768

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use GNU screen's copy and paste commands.

Quick tutorial:

1. Open screen: `screen` (or `screen myprog my args here`)
2. Run your program, producing output you want copied
3. Enter copy mode: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
4. Move your cursor to the start point
5. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Move your cursor to the end point
7. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
8. Paste: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

Screen is much more powerful than that (I use it to tab several virtual terminals without the need for a special terminal emulator, and also so that I don't loose my sessions when X crashes or something).  To get out of screen, simply end your shell session, or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

Comment: Is there a way to paste in other places outside the terminal?

Comment: How has no one built a term with vim keybindings for such a thing

Answer (score 12):

I find [XSel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) is useful in similar situations. It's a tool that manipulates the X selection. For example, this will store the output of your command to the clipboard:

```
grep error error.log | xsel -bi
```

Answer (score 9):

You could also use `tmux` which has [similar capabilities](https://superuser.com/questions/236158/tmux-vs-screen) to `screen`. Once you're in `tmux` and you have the output you want to copy, you can do the following to copy and then paste it:

1. Enter copy mode with <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>, <kbd>[</kbd>
2. Move the cursor with the arrow keys and then start selection with <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>
3. Move the cursor to select the text/region to copy and then copy with <kbd>Alt + W</kbd> (this will immediately exit you from copy mode)
4. You can now paste (within `tmux` only) using <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>

These instructiuons assume *emacs* key bindings are enabled. For the *vi* bindings see this [comparison](https://superuser.com/a/197272) or just follow [this](https://awhan.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/copy-paste-in-tmux/) step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 3):

The OP said he didn't want to do this, but here is a unix utils way to do it for posterity.  If you learn these little unix utilities they can be quite powerful.

> ls $( dirname $( grep error error.log | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 5- ) )

note: syntax from memory

Answer (score 1):

You may send output directly to the concerned xterm using xterm device no. Here is the command.

```
xyz$ls /home/ankit/documents/etc/x/y/z > /dev/pts/0
```

(or watever is the device name, You can get it using command 'w' for opened xterm)

Try it & hope this may solve your problem.

Comment: This doesn't make the output available for re-use.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be using `byobu` which uses either `tmux` or `screen` in the background. It's a wrapper tool that makes using `screen` or `tmux` way more efficient, fast and easy. As such it makes it very simple to copy n paste too.
Once you're in `byobu` and you have the output you want to copy, you can do the following to copy and then paste it:

1. Enter in scroll mode by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>. This mode allows to scroll up and down with arrow keys or <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> keys both in the output of previous commands or in the body of a text editor.
2. Move the cursor with the arrow keys to the point where u want to start copying.
3. Press and release <kbd>Space</kbd> bar.
4. Move the cursor to select the text/region to copy (this looks very similar to vim VISUAL mode)
5. Copy by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this will immediately exit you from scroll mode and copy mode)
6. You can now paste using <kbd>Alt + Insert</kbd> (only within `byobu` by default but u can extend the paste enabled applications by installing xclip and doing some setting in byobu --> watch [Introduction to terminal multiplexers - Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sD5zlW8a5E&t=1058s) from around minute 42 to 48)