# Selecting text in terminal without using the mouse

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

If I'm working in a terminal window in Linux, is there a keyboard shortcut I can use to select output displayed on previous lines? If I select something with the mouse I can copy using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, but is there a way to select without using the mouse at all.  I'm using either Gnome terminal or KDE konsole in Ubuntu desktop.

For example I often need to copy results from a mysql query and then google them.

Comment: You need to add more details. Are you at a "raw" virtual console, or running a console-emulator in e.g. GNOME or something?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312213/how-do-i-copy-text-from-my-xterm-without-a-mouse

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `screen` application and enter copy mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Start selecting text with <kbd>Space</kbd> and end selecting text with <kbd>Space</kbd>. Insert text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: A better explanation how to use screen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312213/

Answer (score 8):

Daniel Micay's [Termite](https://github.com/thestinger/termite/) sports a "selection mode". Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will activate it. It's got vim-like key bindings. <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd> will select à la `vim`'s visual mode, <kbd>y</kbd> will yank, <kbd>Esc</kbd> will exit selection mode.

Comment: Does it allow search in visual mode?

Comment: Applies to [alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Screen and Emacs `M-x shell`, for example, allow for keyboard access to the scrollback buffer. This was also one of the features of Plan 9 (but I guess it was mouse-oriented, at least primarily); you might want to take a look at `9term` and/or Sam, the Plan 9 editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can to it at terminal:

1 - Move the cursor to the beginning of line using  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

```
 $ touch test.txt
```

2 - Copy the line to the paste area <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

3 - Finally, you can past it <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd>

```
$ touch test.txt
```

4- You can do it in a single word or more just using <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> and use <kbd>crtl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> at word's beginning.

Comment: Oooh, composition! I was quite sure I was missing something. Now I can use `ctrl-b` to move back too, and use many other emacs movement shortcuts!

Comment: This does not address the question, which is about selecting text so as to be able to copy to the system clipboard (enabling pasting in other applications).
Instead, this response answers a different, unasked question, i.e. how to copy and paste using the GNU kill ring.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to copy the command(which you typed) without using mouse, you can try this `ctrl` + `space` + `←` OR `→`.

Now you can select the words.

Answer (score -3):

`$ emacs -g '80x24' --eval '(term "/bin/bash")'`

```
    C-c C-k    char mode
    C-c C-j    line mode
    C-space    Selecting text in terminal without using the mouse
    M-w        copy to X11 clipboard
```

C - Ctrl
M - Alt