# Text selection not works on Ubuntu terminal with SHIFT+ARROW (Left or right)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, kde-plasma

Recently I installed Ubuntu and I've some troubles with typing text on terminal, the problems not occurs on the text editors. I can't select the text to right or left using `shift+arrow`. When I try it, like `shift+left`, `D` letter is typed on the line, and `C` is typed using shortcut with arrow right. Resuming, I've two issues:

- Select text with `shift+arrow` not working;
- Select all text with `shift+home` or `shift+end`

I installed KDE on Ubuntu. Please, anyone can help me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/terminal.

Comment: Related: [Using the SHIFT key in Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/31991/301745) on Ask Ubuntu

Comment: Related: [Selecting text in terminal without using the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1536757/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Terminal does not use the same shortcuts (or even the same cursor behavior) as you might expect in a browser or text editor window. The shift key by itself does not select text that way. `shift+home` will scroll to the top, `shift+end` to the bottom, and using it with `pg up`/`pg down` will scroll up/down one screen. The arrow keys are mapped to A/B/C/D.

As you can see on [this list](https://techlog360.com/basic-ubuntu-commands-terminal-shortcuts-linux-beginner/#Ubuntu_Terminal_Shortcuts), most of the commands are for moving around and managing processes. I usually just select text with the mouse, then copy with `ctrl+shift+c` and paste with `ctrl+shift+v`. As discussed on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302263/selecting-text-in-the-terminal-without-using-the-mouse), there appears to be no easy way to select arbitrary text without the mouse.

Alternative terminal programs may offer more options.

**Update** While this is not a standard shortcut, you can go into Terminal's Edit > Preferences > Shortcuts, find the Edit section, click the Select All row in the Shortcut Key column, then enter a new shortcut like `ctrl+shift+a`. This new shortcut will then let you then copy all of the terminal text.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.